# Bot Framework, promptchoice a list of object

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, bots, botframework

I want to ask a user which widget it wants to use after searching for widgets, which results in a list of widgets. I want to be able to click on the name of a widget, and then get the URL of the widget. When I run the following code, I get `invalid need: expected Call, have Poll`.

```
public async Task SelectAfterSearch(IDialogContext context, List<Widget> widgetlist)
{
    PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnWidgetSelected, GetListOfWidgets("list"), "Which one do you want more information about?", "Not a valid option", 3);
}

public async Task OnWidgetSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Widget> result)
{
    var chosen = await result;
    await context.PostAsync($"You have chosen {chosen.Name}: {chosen.Url}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `context.Wait` at the end of your `OnWidgetSelected` method.

```
public async Task OnWidgetSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Widget> result)
{
    var chosen = await result;
    await context.PostAsync($"You have chosen {chosen.Name}: {chosen.Url}");
    context.Wait(...) // => usually you Wait on the MessageReceived method.
}
```

Comment: No. Probably because it doesn't receive result. But the promptdialog is never executed

Comment: `public async Task OnWidgetSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Widget> result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Before await result");
            var chosen = await result;
            await context.PostAsync($"After await result");`

Comment: This only sends back "Before await result".

Comment: Right.. so probably an exception is being thrown. Try doing a try/catch around the await result... and inspect the exception